# Switching multiple bar positions javafx

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, transition

I have a barchat with 5 bars, now I'm trying to move each bar from left to right based on high value (more like a bar chart race from flourish @ https://app.flourish.studio) not the same but the idea is the same.

To check small numbers against big numbers and big numbers against small numbers I'm using random integers.

For example, If barE is greater then all bars and less then barA, it should move to number 2 and replace bar B. I'm using the "if statement" to try and accomplish this. The problem is, only one transition is happening which is the first one. When random numbers change every 3 seconds the correct transition does not happen. Does anyone know how can I correct this problem?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.TimeZone;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;

import javafx.scene.Group;

import javafx.scene.Node;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;

import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;

import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class App extends Application {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    final static String austria = "Austria",  brazil = "Brazil",  france = "France", england = "England", belgium = "Belgium";

    private IntegerProperty secondA,  secondB , secondC, secondD, secondE;

    private Text secondAText, secondBText , secondCText, secondDText, secondEText;



    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Realtime Bar Chart Demo");



        //defining the axes

        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();

        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        xAxis.setAnimated(false);

        yAxis.setAnimated(false);



        //creating the bar chart with two axis

        final BarChart<String,Number> bc =  new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

        bc.setAnimated(false);

        bc.setTitle("Country Summary");

        xAxis.setLabel("Country");

        yAxis.setLabel("Value");



        //defining a series to display data

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesA = new XYChart.Series<>();

        Data<String, Number> dataA = new XYChart.Data<>(austria,0);

        seriesA.getData().add(dataA);

        seriesA.setName("Austra");

        secondA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        secondAText = new Text("");

        secondA.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            dataA.setYValue(newValue);

            secondAText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));

        });

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesB = new XYChart.Series<>();

        Data<String, Number> dataB = new XYChart.Data<>(brazil,0);

        seriesB.getData().add(dataB);

        seriesB.setName("Brazil");

        secondB =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        secondB.bind(secondA.add(0));

        secondBText = new Text("");

        secondB.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            dataB.setYValue(newValue);

            secondBText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));

        });

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesC = new XYChart.Series<>();

        Data<String, Number> dataC = new XYChart.Data<>(france,0);

        seriesC.getData().add(dataC);

        seriesC.setName("France");

        secondC =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        secondC.bind(secondA.add(0));

        secondCText = new Text("");

        secondC.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            dataC.setYValue(newValue);

            secondCText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));

        });



XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesD = new XYChart.Series<>();

        Data<String, Number> dataD = new XYChart.Data<>(england,0);

        seriesD.getData().add(dataD);

        seriesD.setName("England");

        secondD =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        secondD.bind(secondA.add(0));

        secondDText = new Text("");

        secondD.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            dataD.setYValue(newValue);

            secondDText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));

        });



XYChart.Series<String, Number> seriesE = new XYChart.Series<>();

        Data<String, Number> dataE = new XYChart.Data<>(belgium,0);

        seriesE.getData().add(dataE);

        seriesE.setName("Belgium");

        secondE =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

        secondE.bind(secondA.add(0));

        secondEText = new Text("");

        secondE.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            dataE.setYValue(newValue);

            secondEText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));

        });



        // add series to chart

        bc.getData().add(seriesA);

        bc.getData().add(seriesB);

        bc.getData().add(seriesC);

        bc.getData().add(seriesD);

        bc.getData().add(seriesE);



        displayLabelForData(dataA, secondAText);

        displayLabelForData(dataB, secondBText);

        displayLabelForData(dataC, secondCText);

        displayLabelForData(dataD, secondDText);

        displayLabelForData(dataE, secondEText);

        // setup scene

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // show the stage

        primaryStage.show();



        // setup a scheduled executor to periodically put data into the chart

        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();



        // input data onto graph per second        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

double posA = dataA.getNode().localToScene(dataA.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();

double posB = dataB.getNode().localToScene(dataB.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();

double posC = dataC.getNode().localToScene(dataC.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();

double posD = dataD.getNode().localToScene(dataD.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();

double posE = dataE.getNode().localToScene(dataE.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();

TranslateTransition ttA = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), dataA.getNode());

TranslateTransition ttB = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), dataB.getNode());

TranslateTransition ttC = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), dataC.getNode());

TranslateTransition ttD = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), dataD.getNode());

TranslateTransition ttE = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), dataE.getNode());

//Genarate random numbers

Integer randomB = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60);

Integer randomC = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60);

Integer randomD = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60);

Integer randomE = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60);

int intSecondB = secondB.bind(secondA.add(randomB));

int intSecondC = secondC.bind(secondA.add(randomC));

int intSecondD = secondD.bind(secondA.add(randomD));

int intSecondE = secondE.bind(secondA.add(randomE));
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the below if statements or the code itself. To avoid the code for being more long, I only included if statements that compare only seriesB(barB) against other bars.

```
//using if statement to swich each bar based on value

if (intSecondB >= intSecondA && intSecondB >= intSecondB && intSecondB >= intSecondC && intSecondB >= intSecondD && intSecondB >= intSecondE) {

double diffBA = posB - posA;

ttA.setByX(diffBA);

ttB.setByX(-diffBA);



ttA.setCycleCount(1);

    ttA.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttA.play();

ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB >= intSecondC && intSecondB >= intSecondD && intSecondB >= intSecondE) {

System.out.println("keep seriesB(barB) at its position");

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB >= intSecondD && intSecondB >= intSecondE) {

double diffCB = posC - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffCB);

ttC.setByX(-diffCB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttC.setCycleCount(1);

    ttC.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttC.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB >= intSecondE) {

double diffDB = posD - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffDB);

ttD.setByX(-diffDB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttD.setCycleCount(1);

    ttD.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttD.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffEB = posE - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffEB);

ttE.setByX(-diffEB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttE.setCycleCount(1);

    ttE.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttE.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffFB = posF - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffFB);

ttF.setByX(-diffFB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttF.setCycleCount(1);

    ttF.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttF.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffGB = posG - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffGB);

ttG.setByX(-diffGB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttG.setCycleCount(1);

    ttG.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttG.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffHB = posH - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffHB);

ttH.setByX(-diffHB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttH.setCycleCount(1);

    ttH.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttH.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffIB = posI - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffIB);

ttI.setByX(-diffIB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttI.setCycleCount(1);

    ttI.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttI.play();

}

if (intSecondB < intSecondA && intSecondB < intSecondC && intSecondB < intSecondD && intSecondB < intSecondE) {

double diffJB = posJ - posB;

ttB.setByX(diffJB);

ttJ.setByX(-diffJB);



ttB.setCycleCount(1);

    ttB.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttB.play();

ttJ.setCycleCount(1);

    ttJ.setAutoReverse(true);

    ttJ.play();

}

            // Update the chart

            Platform.runLater(() -> {

                secondA.set( cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            });

        }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Override

    public void stop() throws Exception {

        super.stop();

        scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();

    }



    private void displayLabelForData(XYChart.Data<String, Number> data, Text text) {

        final Node node = data.getNode();

        ((Group) node.getParent()).getChildren().add(text);

      node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Bounds>) (ov, oldBounds, bounds) -> {

            text.setLayoutX(

                    Math.round( bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - text.prefWidth(-1) / 2));

            text.setLayoutY(Math.round( bounds.getMinY() - text.prefHeight(-1) * 0.5));

        });

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Just thinking off the top of my head. I would create an `ArrayList` of  `XYChart.Data`. I would then add that data to a chart. Next, I would create a `Timeline`. On ever pulse of the `Timeline`, I would remove all the data from the chart. I would then increment any number values that need to be incremented. Next, I would sort the `ArrayList`. Finally, I would add the list of data back to the chart. I am not 100% sure this will work. It's just me thinking out loud.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one strategy:

1. Create an `ObservableList` for the data
2. Create a `SortedList` from the underlying list
3. Register a listener with the `SortedList`, and when the data change, create an animation:

   a. For each bar, find its current position and the position of the bar in the index corresponding to its new order

   b. Use those positions to animate the `translateX` property of the bar

   c. Animate the `yValue` property of the `XYChart.Data` in the same animation

   d. At the end of the animation, reset the chart data to the new sorted data

There are a couple of little "gotchas" here: you need to turn off `autoRanging` on the `CategoryAxis` (else it will ignore changes to the order of the bars) and reset the categories using the new ordering when you update the data.

Here is an example. I created a class just to hold the data, without any chart API:

```
public static class CountryValue {
    private final String country ;
    private final double value ;
    public CountryValue(String country, double value) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

and a simple data model to hold a list of these:

```
public static class Model {
    private final ObservableList<CountryValue> values ;

    public Model(CountryValue... countryValues) {
        values = FXCollections.observableArrayList(countryValues) ;
    }

    public ObservableList<CountryValue> getValues() {
        return values ;
    }

}
```

Then the key parts look like:

```
    Model model = new Model() ;
    SortedList<CountryValue> sortedData = new SortedList<>(
            model.getValues(), 
            Comparator.comparingDouble(CountryValue::getValue).reversed());

    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> chartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    CategoryAxis countryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    countryAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    populateChartData(sortedData, chartData, countryAxis);

    sortedData.addListener((Change<? extends CountryValue> c) -> {

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline() ;

        for (int newIndex = 0 ; newIndex < sortedData.size() ; newIndex++) {

            CountryValue cv = sortedData.get(newIndex);
            int currentIndex = indexByCountry(cv.getCountry(), chartData);
            Data<String, Number> data = chartData.get(currentIndex);
            double currentX = data.getNode().getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
            double targetX = chartData.get(newIndex).getNode().getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
            DoubleProperty translateXProperty = data.getNode().translateXProperty();
            KeyValue kvx1 = new KeyValue(translateXProperty, 0);
            KeyValue kvx2 = new KeyValue(translateXProperty, targetX - currentX);
            ObjectProperty<Number> yValueProperty = data.YValueProperty();
            KeyValue kvy1 = new KeyValue(yValueProperty, data.getYValue());
            KeyValue kvy2 = new KeyValue(yValueProperty, cv.getValue());
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kvx1),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kvy1),
                    new KeyFrame(animationDuration, kvx2),
                    new KeyFrame(animationDuration, kvy2)
            );
        }

        timeline.setOnFinished(e -> populateChartData(sortedData, chartData, countryAxis));

        timeline.play();
    });
```

The utility `populateChartData()` method updates both the category axis and the data:

```
private void populateChartData(ObservableList<CountryValue> source, 
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> chartData,
        CategoryAxis countryAxis) {

    countryAxis.getCategories().setAll(
        source.stream()
            .map(CountryValue::getCountry)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );

    chartData.setAll(
        source.stream()
            .map(cv -> new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(cv.getCountry(), cv.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

Here's a complete example. The animation is a little "jerky"; I think because the y-axis scale changes in an unpredictable way. You could manage this yourself by turning off autoranging on the y-axis, computing the max y value from the new data, and animating the y-axis range as well as the bars. Also note that it's important no updates to the data happen while the animation is running (else you'll end up with multiple animations running at once). Here that's simply managed by timing, but a more robust solution would check for that and either throttle updates or just end the current animation before starting a new one.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class FlourishChart extends Application {

    private final Duration animationDuration = Duration.millis(250);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Model model = new Model() ;
        Simulator simulator = new Simulator(model);

        SortedList<CountryValue> sortedData = new SortedList<>(
                model.getValues(), 
                Comparator.comparingDouble(CountryValue::getValue).reversed());

        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> chartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        CategoryAxis countryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        countryAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        populateChartData(sortedData, chartData, countryAxis);


        BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(countryAxis, new NumberAxis());
        // turn off default animation:
        chart.setAnimated(false);
        Series<String, Number> series = new Series<>(chartData);
        chart.getData().add(series);

        // when sorted data change, animate bar chart nodes
        // at end of animation, update chart data with new data
        sortedData.addListener((Change<? extends CountryValue> c) -> {

            Timeline timeline = new Timeline() ;

            for (int newIndex = 0 ; newIndex < sortedData.size() ; newIndex++) {

                CountryValue cv = sortedData.get(newIndex);
                int currentIndex = indexByCountry(cv.getCountry(), chartData);
                Data<String, Number> data = chartData.get(currentIndex);
                double currentX = data.getNode().getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
                double targetX = chartData.get(newIndex).getNode().getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
                DoubleProperty translateXProperty = data.getNode().translateXProperty();
                KeyValue kvx1 = new KeyValue(translateXProperty, 0);
                KeyValue kvx2 = new KeyValue(translateXProperty, targetX - currentX);
                ObjectProperty<Number> yValueProperty = data.YValueProperty();
                KeyValue kvy1 = new KeyValue(yValueProperty, data.getYValue());
                KeyValue kvy2 = new KeyValue(yValueProperty, cv.getValue());
                timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kvx1),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kvy1),
                        new KeyFrame(animationDuration, kvx2),
                        new KeyFrame(animationDuration, kvy2)
                );
            }

            timeline.setOnFinished(e -> populateChartData(sortedData, chartData, countryAxis));

            timeline.play();
        });


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        new Thread(simulator).start();
    }



    private int indexByCountry(String country, ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> chartData) {
        for (int index = 0 ; index < chartData.size(); index++) {
            if (chartData.get(index).getXValue().equals(country))
                return index ;
        }
        return -1 ;
    }

    private void populateChartData(ObservableList<CountryValue> source, 
            ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> chartData,
            CategoryAxis countryAxis) {

        countryAxis.getCategories().setAll(
            source.stream()
                .map(CountryValue::getCountry)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );

        chartData.setAll(
            source.stream()
                .map(cv -> new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(cv.getCountry(), cv.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }

    public static class Model {
        private final ObservableList<CountryValue> values ;

        public Model(CountryValue... countryValues) {
            values = FXCollections.observableArrayList(countryValues) ;
        }

        public ObservableList<CountryValue> getValues() {
            return values ;
        }

    }


    // replace with record when they are standard in Java:
    public static class CountryValue {
        private final String country ;
        private final double value ;
        public CountryValue(String country, double value) {
            super();
            this.country = country;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }
        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    // Not really relevant to problem; just simulates changing data in model
    public class Simulator implements Runnable {

        private final Model model ;
        private final Random rng = new Random();

        public Simulator(Model model) {
            this.model = model ;
            createData();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                Platform.runLater(this::createData);
            }
        }

        private void createData() {
            model.getValues().setAll(
                Stream.of("Austria", "Brazil", "France", "England", "Belgium")
                    .map(country -> new CountryValue(country, 50 * rng.nextDouble() + 50))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```