# Sorted Bar Graph in Javafx Chart

Tags: java, javafx, charts, data-visualization

I'm new to JavaFx, currently I'm able to draw a javaFx bar graph, but I want to sort by frequency(so the bar with the highest frequency is at the top or bottom), is there a way to do this? Since I use data from another prgram to draw this, I cannot sort it before adding it to my bar graph, is there a way to sort this bar graph after data is already added to it? Thanks!

Edit: I also want to know is it possible that after sorting it, can the bar graph just display the top 5 category? How can I achieve this.

[My current bar graph using JavaFx bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9Fz.png)

Comment: Maybe a `SortedList`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088133/230513)?

Answer (score 4):

This is just a straight basic java question.  Take the list of input data, sort it in reverse order, then take just the first five values from the resultant list:

```
List<Integer> entries = List.of(8,3,6,1,3,2,0,10,4);
List<Integer> topEntries = entries.stream()
        .sorted(
                Comparator.comparingInt(
                        i -> (int) i
                ).reversed()
        ).limit(
                5
        ).toList();

System.out.println(
        "topEntries = " + topEntries
);
```

Output:

```
topEntries = [10, 8, 6, 4, 3]
```

Then take the resultant sorted, truncated list and use that as input to display your chart (as you had done previously).

You could use a [`SortedList` as suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088133/230513), but you also want to truncate the list to the top five values and a sorted list won't help you with that. So, I'd just use a new list for that and manually regenerate the chart series if the input data changes.